# Problem with creating a single row matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, matrix

I have this for loop that creates a matrix of 1825 columns. This matrix contains a value that ranges from 0 to 1 with increments of 0.013888888889 and a step increment of 25 (so after 25 zeros it goes to 0.013888888889 and then after 25 times it increases again). My problem is that the last 25 columns containing 1s are not created. Instead of a matrix with `1x1825`, I get a matrix of `1x1800` without the 1s. This is the code:

```matlab
coutput=repmat([0], 1,25);
for n=0.013888888889:0.013888888889:1 

    coutput = [coutput repmat([n],1,25)];

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from your loop variable:

```matlab
n = 0.013888888889:0.013888888889:1
```

Let's compare:

```matlab
temp = 0:0.013888888889:1;
temp([1 2 end-1 end])

n = 72;
temp = linspace(0, 1, n+1);
temp([1 2 end-1 end])
```

We get:

```
ans =
   0.00000   0.01389   0.97222   0.98611

ans =
   0.00000   0.01389   0.98611   1.00000
```

Using your solution, we get a vector with dimensions `1x72`, whereas the "more exact" version gives a vector with dimensions `1x73`. So, in the end, it's some rounding issue.

The remaining part can be simplified by using your `repmat` and [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html):

```matlab
k = 25;
out = reshape(repmat(temp, k, 1), 1, (n+1) * k)
```

(Output omitted here.)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

As HansHirse indicated above, this is a rounding issue. You should not use floating-point values as loop indices.

The simple and correct way of implementing your loop is this:

```matlab
for n=1:72
   n = ii/72;
   %...
end
```

But of course this code would be a lot more efficient using Hans’ `repmat`+`reshape` solution because it avoids repeatedly reallocating the output array inside the loop.